# Does the Whonix linux distribution hide your real IP from malicious Tor exit nodes?

Tags: tor, whonix

Does Whonix Linux distro hide your IP address if the traffic goes through a malicious Tor exit node 
or 
does it just hide the IP address against malicious software?

Comment: Tor itself hides your IP from malicious exit node. It doesn't protect you from malicious software through. Otherwise your question is rather broad; there are a lot of ways in which Whonix (or any other distro) might be subverted to leak your IP or expose you to malicious code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whonix does not hide your IP address. It's just a Linux distribution having focus on security relevant software. The Tor network as such tries to hide your IP address for the end points you connect to (e.g. a website).

When your traffic goes through a malicious exit node, then the exit node cannot determine the source the traffic comes from (your IP address) because your traffic was rerouted several times amongst the tor middle nodes.

But when the connection to the end point you requested (e.g. the website) is unencrypted (so the website request URI starts with `http://` instead of `https://`), then the exit node can record all the data that your transferred over the connection: In clear text! This includes especially passwords!